# Bazel cmake error when building rust crates

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, cmake, bazel, librdkafka

I am trying to build a rust crate that uses 2 crates that rely on c libraries using Bazel. The crates are `rdkafka` and `paho-mqttt`.
I am using Bazel `rust_rules`, especially the `crate_universe` rules to build the crate. This is the dependencies section of the `Cargo.toml` of my crate:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.163", features = ["derive"] }
chrono = { version = "0.4.26", features = ["serde"] }
uuid = { version = "1.3.3", features = ["v7", "serde"] }
rdkafka = { version = "0.31", features = ["cmake-build"] }
paho-mqtt = { version = "0.11" }
```

And this is the relevant bazel `WORKSPACE` file (`crate_repository` definition) and the Bazel `BUILD` file for my crate:

```
crates_repository(
    name = "crate_index",
    cargo_lockfile = "//my-crate:Cargo.lock",
    lockfile = "//my-crate:Cargo.Bazel.lock",
    manifests = ["//my-crate:Cargo.toml"],
    annotations = {
        "uuid": [crate.annotation(
            rustc_flags = ["--cfg=uuid_unstable"],
        )],
    },
)

load("@crate_index//:defs.bzl", "crate_repositories")

crate_repositories()
```

```
load("@crate_index//:defs.bzl", "all_crate_deps")
load("@rules_rust//rust:defs.bzl", "rust_library")

rust_library(
    name = "my-crate",
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.rs"]),
    deps = all_crate_deps(
        normal = True,
    ),
)
```

When I run `bazel build //my-crate` I get the following errors:

```
--stderr:
Building and linking librdkafka statically
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.

thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit status: 1
```

This error is reported by both crates (`rdkafka` and `paho-mqtt`) as I have tried to remove the feature 'build-cmake' from `rdkafka` to see if that was the unique library that reported the issue, so I guess that the error would appear in all crates that relies on a C library and on cmake to build and link that library.

#### What I have tried

I have tried to build the crate by using `cargo build` and it works, so I guess that the error is not related to the installation of my system cmake.
I tried to define the `CMAKE_ROOT` and `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` using `export CMAKE_ROOT=/path` and also running bazel with `--action_env=CMAKE_ROOT=/path` and `use_default_shell_env=True` but with no luck, it gives the same error.

#### What may work

I got some suggestions in the Bazel slack (thanks Brian Myers) about using bazel to not only compile `rdkafka` but also for compiling librdkafka but I would like to understand why Bazel is reporting the `cmake` error and how could I fix it to simplify my bazel configuration until I feel more comfortable using Bazel.

#### Additional information

- OS: Arch
- Bazel version: 6.2.1
- CMake version: 3.26.4
- Rust version and the definition of the Bazel toolchain:

```
rust_register_toolchains(
    edition = "2021",
    versions = [
        "1.70.0"
    ],
)
```

---

As I mentioned, why does Bazel report the error? How could I solve the `cmake` error to avoid compiling `librdkafka` on Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building `rdkafka` in bazel and linking it by disabling the `rdkafka-sys` build script. Here are the steps:

1. Add `rules_foreign_cc` and `rdkafka` sources to your `WORKSPACE.bazel`

```
http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    # sha256 = "...",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.5.1",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.5.1.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

# rdkafka source code repository
_ALL_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""
http_archive(
    name = "rdkafka",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    strip_prefix = "librdkafka-2.2.0",
    url = "https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/archive/refs/tags/v2.2.0.tar.gz",
)
```

2. Build `rdkfaka` by invoking `cmake` in your `BUILD.bazel`:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "rdkafka",
    build_args = [
        "--verbose",
        "--",  # <- Pass remaining options to the native tool.
        "-j 12",
    ],
    lib_source = "@rdkafka//:all_srcs",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    out_shared_libs = ["librdkafka.so.1", "librdkafka.so"]
)
```

3. Disable the execution of `build.rs` in `rdkafka-sys` by adding the following annotation to your `crate_universe` in `WORKSPACE`:

```
annotations = {
    "rdkafka-sys": [crate.annotation(
        gen_build_script = False,
    )],
}
```

4. And finally, add your own `rdkafka` dependency to your crate (in `BUILD`):

```
rust_library(
    name = "my-lib",
    srcs = glob([
        "src/**/*.rs",
    ]),
    deps = all_crate_deps() + ["//:rdkafka"],
)
```

Note: You'll also need to set the feature-flag for `rdkafka` to dynamic linking, e.g., in Cargo.toml:

`rdkafka = { version = "0.34.0", features = ["dynamic-linking"], optional = true }`

Or alternatively, you can set it in  the `rust_library` if you're not syncing Cargo with bazel.